# Transfer Items between Views with Drag-and-Drop in Eclipse RCP?

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, eclipse-rcp, transfer

I have 2 views in my application. In one of the views I can see a TreeStructure containing custom defined elements (such as MDocument, MVersion...).

I would like to be able to drag items of type MVersion from my view to the other one but I don't know how to declare the transfer types or to check if the item selected is a supported type.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [`LocalSelectionTransfer`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/util/LocalSelectionTransfer.html). Once you have added drag/drop support to your viewers...

You set the `ISelection` that is dragged in `DragSourceListener.dragStart()` method:

```
LocalSelectionTransfer.getTransfer().setSelection(selection);
```

In the `DropTargetListener.drop()` you check if the type is supported and retrieve the selection:

```
if (LocalSelectionTransfer.getTransfer().isSupportedType(event.currentDataType))
    ISelection sel = LocalSelectionTransfer.getTransfer().getSelection();
    ...
```

Comment: any idea about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28706697/transferdata-is-null-during-drag-on-linux) ?  <:-((