# Java SWT: Drag / Drop

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, swt

I want to drag & drop nodes in a `TreeViewer` to reorder them. The nodes in my tree wrap an `IJavaElement` or an `IFile`. 
My problem is that none of my attempts to place these node-values in the drag-event are accessible once the drop event is executed (=`null`). Apparently, I got something wrong with this `TransferHandles` you have to use or create.

```
   @Override
    public void dragSetData(DragSourceEvent event) {     
        IStructuredSelection selections = treeViewer.getSelections();
        IBookmark dragNode = (IBookmark) selections.getFirstElement();

        //There is only 1 transfer handle as return
        event.dataType = FileTransfer.getInstance().getSupportedTypes()[0];
        event.data = dragNode.getValue();//<-- Returns my IFile
```

It should work this way, but nothing reaches my drop listener. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

**Edit:**

Is there a way to place the current instance of the object that is dragged into the drag-event? I am only working within Eclipse in my own view for this operation. And I am actually more interested in the instance of the object that is dropped than just the value of the node.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your code why you get *null* in your drop event (in case of incompatible transfer types, you wouldn't get to drop at all). However, setting *dataType* in `dragSetData()` has no effect. Transfer types should be configured using `addDragSupport` and `addDropSupport` of [`StructuredViewer`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/StructuredViewer.html).

> Is there a way to place the current instance of the object that is dragged into the drag-event?

You can use `LocalSelectionTransfer` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8479318/150166).