# TransferData is null during Drag on Linux

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jface

When I drag a node from Project Explorer onto TreeViewer DnD works fine on Windows, but does not work on Linux.

During debugging I see that TransferData has data on Windows

[image]
But does not when debug on Linux

[image]
Searching for possible cause didn't reveal anything. Any ideas what could be the problem here?

Comment: Please show the DnD code. Besides, the Linux screen shot also shows transferData

Comment: You are right, I erroneously said that TransferData is null, I meant the data in TransferData does not resolve to anything useful.

My DropTargetAdapter extends EditingDomainViewerDropAdapter, from the debugging that I did I see that on Linux ByteArrayTransfer.nativeToJava() always returns null until I drop the object, and dragSource is being called per each drag event. On Windows ByteArrayTransfer.nativeToJava() returns non-empty array when I drag onto the TreeViewer.

Comment: Can you edit the question? That would be a lot easier to read.

Comment: @Alex HELP: did you find a solution to your problem? I'm in the same deep "sheet" :)

Comment: @Campa no I did not :(

Comment: too bad U_U In the end, being an RCP-er now, I declared an OSGi service to act as buffer for drag mouse selections so I could get/set my instances there.